# How to keep div on the left of the screen regardless of screen size?

Tags: css

I'm currently working on a site that uses a slider at some point, but instead of the regular arrows that are inside the slider (left and right arrows, for slider navigation) I need to get the left one attached to the left of the screen regardless of screen size and the same with the right arrow. It only works with my screen size currently (1366x768) and the code is

```
.bx-prev {
margin-left:-16.2%;
position:absolute;
margin-top:-200px;
}

.bx-next{
margin-left:86.2%;
position:absolute;
margin-top:-200px;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Also if it could be done best in Javascript/jQuery, I'm also open to that.

Comment: NB: If you are using `position: absolute` with margins instead of `top`/`left`/`bottom`/`right`, you are probably do something wrong.

Comment: If I use top/left/bottom/right it will stay inside of the slider .. i need to break it out and attach it to the left and right edge of the screen respectively.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add `position:relative` to the parent element then you can use `position:absolute`; in related to the parent element

```
.bx-prev {

position:absolute;
top:200px;
left: 0px;
    height:10px;
    width:10px;
    background:lime;
}

.bx-next{
    top:200px;
 height:10px;
    width:10px;
    background:lime;
position:absolute;

right: 0px;
}
.slider{
position:relative;
    width:500px;
        height:500px;
    background:red;
}   

<div class="slider">
    <div class="bx-next"></div>
    <div class="bx-prev"></div>
</div>
```

[sample](http://jsfiddle.net/MmggJ/)

Answer (score 4):

You are using absolute positioning so you can do:

```
.bx-prev {
margin-left:-16.2%;
position:absolute;
margin-top:-200px;
left: 0px;
}

.bx-next{
margin-left:86.2%;
position:absolute;
margin-top:-200px;
right: 0px;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't change anything for the left arrow, a cap between the left screen edge and the arrow will appear if screen bigger and if smaller the arrow will just be hidden by the screen's left edge .. the right arrow is just disappeared way too far into the screen's right edge.

Answer (score 1):

Absolute positioning takes the element out of its container and allows you to freely position it on the document using `top`/`bottom`/`left`/`right`.

Here is a jsfiddle which shows `b` inside `a` in the markup, but I've postioned it to the far left. This is the same with `c` at the right.

http://jsfiddle.net/w2CsF/1/

Answer (score -1):

```
position: fixed;
```

Is the answer to your question.

Comment: I don't think you fully understood me or I just suck at explaining, but what I mean is that whenever the screen size is bigger there will appear a space between the left screen and the arrow, it's not attached to it.